Is there a command line tool to convert Opus to WebM?
Is anyone aware of a linux command line tool to convert Opus files to WebM (audio only)? FFmpeg is not an option. Thanks!

If ffmpeg is not an option, then mkvmerge from the mkvtoolnix package.
mkvmerge -o output.webm input.opus

